# How do I write a date format for 2011-08-16T23:20:30.000Z in PHP?

Tags: php, date, date-format

I have dates coming over in this format:
2011-08-16T23:20:30.000Z

I am trying to do something like this:

`$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u',$issue->updated);`

I have two problems:

1. I know Z is for UTC, but the timezone placeholders [in the PHP docs](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) don't match Z
2. How do I escape just the T but not the H? The escape comment in the [PHP doc for date](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) makes it seem like a slash will escape all characters until a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and you can pass it straight to the constructor, e.g:

```
var_dump(new DateTime("2011-08-16T23:20:30.000Z"));
```

...

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2011-08-16 23:20:30"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
```

Comment: Wow, I am brain dead! The real issue was I was using n instead of j on the original date format output that I was troubleshooting... so I was thinking there was a problem with the date itself. Marking this complete shortly as it's the correct answer.